# How can I pull images from Flickr into Drupal website based on specified tags?

Tags: drupal, module, tags, flickr

I work for a registered children's charity and social enterprise, and we've recently relaunched our website - built on Drupal, which is great.

To help bring to life what we do, we serve a random selection of images across the site - simply pulling them from one of our own generic 'best of' sets on Flickr - but desperately need to filter these for different sections of the site, so they are more relevant.  The most obvious, flexible and efficient option would be to call images from Flickr based on tags, only the main Flickr module doesn't appear to allow for this.

Having spoken with our IT guy, we came up with the below (which is pretty exhaustive, so happy to be flexible for speedy solution).

Hope someone on here can help - and at a reasonable rate..!

---

Essentially we need a field type similar to that used by the existing flickr module photo set; one that can be attached to any content type but allows the input of one or more flickr tags (as opposed to just single photo or set as is currently the case).  As with the existing flickr photo set, we also need a content pane/block to present a random flickr photo based on the tag(s) specified.

Ideally, on the content creation/edit form, the user would be presented with a list of qualified tags pulled from the flickr account.  Failing that, tags entered should be validated as having one or more flickr photos from the specified account on form submission.

As is the case with the standard module, when images are clicked on, a new page should open on the main flickr site showing this image (with the usual related set/tag based images).

Answer (score 0):

Flickr has a very nice API. You should install `flickr` module from Drupal.org then create a custom module to get and display images from your flickr account.

Flickr module has a function you can use to make your own API calls to flickr: `flickr_request(method, params)`. Here's how you can search photos by tags on flickr: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html

Hope this can lead you to the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks Marius.  Certainly makes sense (although if it's so easy, baffles me why I've had such little take up frmo the drupal community on this).  Either way, have finally commissioned a developer to build the module for us, and passed on your comments - can only hope we're not overpaying!! ;)

Comment: Well, I learned this the hard way. I had to do a project and couldn't find any help so I helped myself :)